# How to add inline CSS style in Custom Text of Views?

Tags: views, theming, 9

I have already setup fields for user to input color code (e.g. "#123000") to a content type. Now I need to modify the inline style color / background-color with the given value. I tried to do this in my Custom Text field:

```
    <div class="box" style="color: {{ color_field }}">
        <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
        <span class="description">{{ body }}</span>
    </div>
```

But the rendered output would become:

```html
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Dummy</h2>
        <span class="description">Some dummy description...</span>
    </div>
```

I went as far as creating my own Twig function implementation:

```
    <div class="box" {{ my_dummy_function(color_field) }}>
        <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
        <span class="description">{{ body }}</span>
    </div>
```

The function would supposedly output `style="color: color_field_value"`, but the whole attribute would be "eaten" by Drupal's rendering chain. Even adding a `| raw` filter after that would not change a thing.

```html
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Dummy</h2>
        <span class="description">Some dummy description...</span>
    </div>
```

In desperate, I modified my dummy Twig function to output `hello="world"`, and the attribute would be rendered normally:

```html
    <div class="box" hello="world">
        <h2>Dummy</h2>
        <span class="description">Some dummy description...</span>
    </div>
```

But if it output something like `hello="color: world"`:

```html
    <div class="box" hello=" world">
        <h2>Dummy</h2>
        <span class="description">Some dummy description...</span>
    </div>
```

So it seems there are some keyword-based filtering going on. And I can't seem to have a way to render anything resembling inline CSS. Is there anyway I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem I've encountered numerous times, and personally I've never had any luck outputting inline styles in a Views field that's been rewritten through the UI.

My solution has always been to create a template file that takes responsibility for rendering the view fields, as that does allow you to use inline styles.

In your case, you could have the file in your theme's /templates folder (I have them in a /views subdirectory), with a filename like:

```
views-view-fields--your-view-name.html.twig
```

You'd then just need to slightly tweak the markup you already have:

```
<div class="box" style="color: {{ fields.field_color_field.content }}">
    <h2>{{ fields.title.content }}</h2>
    <span class="description">{{ fields.body.content }}</span>
</div>
```